# How to include a count condition within a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have created the following:

```
from itertools import product
x = [(b0, b1, b2, b3) for b0, b1, b2, b3 in product(range(5), repeat=4)]
```

This creates all tuples from `[0,0,0,0]` to `[4,4,4,4]`.

I would like as a condition to only include those tuples which do not have the same number repeated more than 2 times. So I would like to ignore such tuples as `[2,2,2,1]` or `[3,3,3,3]` while keeping tuples such as `[0,0,1,2]` or `[1,3,4,2]`

I tried the following and I think it is ok but it appears rather cumbersome.

```
y = [(b0, b1, b2, b3) for b0, b1, b2, b3 in product(range(5), repeat=4) if (b0, b1, b2, b3).count(0)<=2 and (b0, b1, b2, b3).count(1)<=2 and (b0, b1, b2, b3).count(2)<=2 and (b0, b1, b2, b3).count(3)<=2  and (b0, b1, b2, b3).count(4)<=2]
```

Perhaps a way to count each of the elements from `[0,1,2,3,4]` and take their max and state that the max<=2.

How is it possible to include with a list comprehension a counting condition?

Comment: How about `x = [t for t in product(range(5), repeat=4) if len(set(t)) > 2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `set` might work. Another option is to use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product
x =  [
     comb for comb in product(range(5), repeat=4)
     if max(Counter(comb).values()) <= 2
     ]
```

Comment: Yes, this seems more like I was thinking about. In testing your solution I noticed that I had missed a case in my original code (now been corrected). Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a generator to produce your tuples, and check your condition with a `Counter`:

```
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter

def selected_tuples():
    for t in product(range(5), repeat=4):
        if Counter(t).most_common(1)[0][1]<=2:
            yield t

print(list(selected_tuples()))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 1, 3), (0, 0, 1, 4), ...]
```

Comment: While I do like generators, I thiink that is a bit of an overkill to use them here, depending on where the final code is to be used of course.